# Common algorithm for maps with different comparison functions

Tags: c++

I have a common algorithm for 2 maps that uses find() and operator[] to access the map. However, elsewhere in the code I need to iterate over these maps and one of them needs to be sorted with a reverse comparison from the other. I ended up using the reverse iterator for that map, but profiling shows me that a huge amount of time is wasted on dereferencing the reverse iterator. I tried to do the following, but it obviously didn't work:

```
struct Custom
{
    list<double> Doubles;
    int Integer = 0;
};

typedef map<double, Custom> CustomMap;
typedef map<double, Custom, std::greater<double>> CustomMapGreater;

CustomMap A;
CustomMapGreater B;

...

void Algorithm(bool aChosen)
{
    CustomMap* chosenMap;

    if (aChosen)
    {
        chosenMap = &A;
    }
    else
    {
        chosenMap = &B;    // Conversion not possible
    }

    // Algorithm that uses chosenMap follows
    ...
}
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to work? I have a feeling something can be done with templates, but I'm not very proficient with generic programming.

Comment: How did you profile? Make sure to enable optimizations when profiling. Reverse iterators add a layer of complexity that can often be optimized out.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I used the performance wizard in MSVC, compiled with maximize speed optimization

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but can't you just template the algorithm with the map type as T?

Comment: Why do you have to iterate from the reverse for one of the maps? And can't you solve your problem using templates, passing the selected map as argument to a generic function?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Unfortunately the overall program is very large and complex, and I doubt I can extract a snippet that would reproduce this

Comment: @ErikAlapää , as I said, I'm not so great with templates yet.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have to reverse iterate because of the way the data is received / handled elsewhere in the code

Comment: boost.multi_index was created for just this kind of thing.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html

Comment: @RichardHodges I would rather not use boost unless absolutely necessary.  It adds too much to compile and link times

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The template way look like:

```
template <typename Map>
void Algorithm(Map& map)
{
    // ...
}
```

or, in your specific case, even

```
template <typename Comp>
void Algorithm(std::map<double, Custom, Comp>& map)
{
    // ...
}
```

and then

```
void AlgorithmChooser(bool aChosen)
{
    if (aChosen) {
        Algorithm(A);
    } else {
        Algorithm(B);
    }
}
```

Comment: As `std::less` and `std::greater` are compatible by signature it should work even without template

Comment: @Slava: There are 2 different classes. (with equivalent `operator()`). The comparer could be changed to be `bool (*)(const T&, const T&)` and be passed in constructor...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same type for both maps:

```
typedef map<double, Custom, std::binary_function<const Custom &, const Custom &,bool>> CustomMap;

CustomMap lessMap( std::less<Custom>() );
CustomMap greaterMap( std::greater<Custom>() );
```

then you can pass them as the same type to a function or assign them to a pointer to `CustomMap`. Or for C++11 and later:

```
typedef map<double, Custom, std::function<bool( const Custom &, const Custom &)>> CustomMap;
```